# store a KVM .qcow2 image in NTFS external hard disk

Tags: debian, kvm, qemu, qcow2

I have a .qcow2 image that became really bigger (36 GB) and I want to move it to an external HD to avoid using all my PC (Debian machine) memory for that. Is it possible to store it (and access it directly from the HD) on a NTFS HD or there would be problems of some kind? Does it need to be ext4 etc. ?

Thank you very much in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

What about to move `/var/lib/libvirt/images` to that disk?

You didn't give many details... try this:

```
https://www.unixarena.com/2015/12/linux-kvm-change-libvirt-vm-image-store-path.html/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that Debian comes with NTFS support. Try mounting the drive. If you can't mount it, try installing the appropriate package (not sure what it's named on Debian). Once you get it mounted, you shouldn't have any issues storing your file on there.